# Nodejs how to use the callback result of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning nodejs by writing an app to manage my Philips hue lights and I have a problem with the way nodejs works.

I have a function that is supposed to get all ids of the lights:

```
id = [];

function getLightsId() {
    args = {
        path: {
            "username": "myusername"
        }
    };

    client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://192.168.0.10/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

    client.methods.getLightState(args, function (data, response) {
        for (key in data) {
            id.push(key);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that whenever I want to use my id array, its empty because nodejs didnt processed the getLightsId callback function.

ps : I am using node-rest-client to interact with my API.

Comment: this has nothing to do with nodejs, this is a javascript issue

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call. It applies to all async processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It processed your callback alright, it's just that the function is **asynchronous**. Meaning that when you try and use the `id` variable later on, it is still processing from the above callback. You need to pass in another callback and pass your `id` variable to that once it's been filled:

```
function getLightsId(callback){
    args ={
        path:{"username":"myusername"}
    };

    client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://192.168.0.10/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

    client.methods.getLightState(args, function(data,response){
        var id = [];
        for(key in data){
            id.push(key);
        }
        callback(id);
    });
}
```

And you would call this like:

```
getLightsId(function(idArray) {
    console.log(idArray); //here they are
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach is to use a promises library, like [**promised-io**](https://github.com/kriszyp/promised-io), it's just one of the ways to avoid "callback hell".

```
var Deferred = require('promised-io/promise').Deferred;

id = [];

function getLightsId() {
    var deferred = new Deffered;

    args = {
        path: {
            "username": "myusername"
        }
    };

    client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://192.168.0.10/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

    client.methods.getLightState(args, function (data, response) {
        for (key in data) {
            id.push(key);
        }

        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

getLightsId().then(function(){
    // Now you have the id[]s
});
```

Comment: Well, i just want to store my id's in an array, so i can use this array in other functions easily.

Comment: @user3473514, then this will work for you, I've left your `id` array in the global scope, and you'll be able to access it when the promise is resolved (where I commented).